# Filter nested collection by intersecting another list

Tags: c#, linq

Suppose I have the following class.

```
class Foo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public List<Foo> Children { get; set; }
}
```

and the following array of Ids

```
int[] ids = new int[] { 1, 3, 5 };
```

and the following two object

```
var myParentChildrenMatchesFoo = new Foo
{
    Id = 1,
    Children = new List<Foo>
    {
        new Foo {
            Id = 3,
            Children = null
        },
        new Foo {
            Id = 2,
            Children = null
        },
        new Foo {
            Id = 5,
            Children = null
        }
    }
};

var myParentNoMatchesFoo = new Foo
{
    Id = 2,
    Children = new List<Foo>
    {
        new Foo {
            Id = 3,
            Children = null
        },
        new Foo {
            Id = 2,
            Children = null
        },
        new Foo {
            Id = 5,
            Children = null
        }
    }
};

var myChildrenNoMatchesFoo = new Foo
{
    Id = 1,
    Children = new List<Foo>
    {
        new Foo {
            Id = 2,
            Children = null
        },
        new Foo {
            Id = 4,
            Children = null
        },
        new Foo {
            Id = 6,
            Children = null
        }
    }
};
var myNoMatchesFoo = new Foo
{
    Id = 1,
    Children = new List<Foo>
    {
        new Foo {
            Id = 2,
            Children = null
        },
        new Foo {
            Id = 4,
            Children = null
        },
        new Foo {
            Id = 6,
            Children = null
        }
    }
};
```

How can I return matching records based on the intersection of my ids array preserving the parent if a child matches but a parent doesn't and only returning children that match?

Expected results:

```
myParentChildrenMatchesFoo { Id: 1, Children: [{ Id: 3, Children: []}, { Id: 5, Children: []}] }

myParentNoMatchesFoo { Id: 1, Children: [{ Id: 3, Children: []}, { Id: 5, Children: []}] }

myChildrenNoMatchesFoo { Id: 1, Children: [] }

myNoMatchesFoo { }
```

Here's the direction I'm currently going. I added everything to a list so I could use Linq.

```
List<Foo> myFoo = new List<Foo>();
myFoo.Add(myChildrenNoMatchesFoo);
myFoo.Add(myNoMatchesFoo);
myFoo.Add(myParentChildrenMatchesFoo);
myFoo.Add(myParentNoMatchesFoo);
```

And I'm using the overload of .SelectMany to search only the children and flatten the object.

```
var test = myFoo
   .SelectMany(c => c.Children, (parent, child) => new { parent = parent, child = child }).Where(c => ids.Contains(c.child.Id))
   .Select(p => new Foo()
            {
                Id = p.parent.Id,
                Children = new List<Foo>() { p.child }
            })
   .ToList();
```

I could then .GroupBy the parent Id to put it all back together but it seems like there should be a better way. I know that I could build a new object in two nested loops very easily or I could probably create a helper extension that would do what I want but I'm trying to find a Linq-only method, if for no other reason than to see if I can.

Comment: Is it possible for the `Children` to nest more than one layer deep, and do you want to return the tree up to the parent for matching deeper `Children`?

Comment: Also, what do you mean by "preserving parent" ? You can't return the same object and change the contents of `Children`. Also your sample answers don't match your sample data.

Comment: Also, what does the expected result for `myNoMatchesFoo` represent? An empty anonymous object? And what does `[]` represent?

Comment: The key take away is that I do need to change the contents of children. It's simple enough to return the parent and all children if any combination of items match. And yes, I had a typo.

Comment: The [] is an empty array. The ancestor furthest down the tree will never have a value. I expressed it as JSON for readability. I don't really care how empty/null values are expressed.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the code below works. It's incredibly ugly and unreadable. I'm going to work backwards to see if I can clean it up or simplify it.

```
var wow = myFoo
        .SelectMany(c => c.Children, (parent, child) => new { parent = parent, child = child })
        .Where(p => ids.Contains(p.parent.Id) || ids.Contains(p.child.Id))
        .Select(p => new
        {
            Id = p.parent.Id,
            Children = p.child
        })
        .GroupBy(g => g.Id, (key, group) => new { Id = key, group = group.Select(g => g.Children) })
        .Select(g => new
        {
            Id = g.Id,
            Children = g.group.Where(c => ids.Contains(c.Id)).ToList()
        }).ToList();
```